# How to stack divs vertically on mobile but keep them horizontal on web version?

Tags: css

I added some div tags to create two columns in a wordpress post. Here is the code I used:

```
#container {
   width:100%;
}
#one {
   width:50%;
   float:left;
}
#two {
   width:50%;
   float:right;
}
```

I added the code above to my style.css file.

When viewed on my webpage everything looks fine. However, when viewed on mobile it looks bad. Code below is what I added to post:

```
<div id="container">
<div id="one">content here</div>
<div id="two">content here</div>
</div>
```

What I'd like to do is stack the divs vertically when viewed on a mobile device. Is there a fairly simple way to do this for someone that has limited coding experience?

Thanks

Comment: you may use a frontend framework like bootstrap (http://bootstrap.com)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Take a look at media queries.

```
@media all and (max-width:800px) //800px for tablets and phones.
{
    #one, #two
    {
        display: block; 
        float: none; 
        width: 100%;
    }
}
```

Note that this has to go after your code above, unless you make the selectors more specific.

Comment: Awesome, this worked. I didn't try the other suggestions because this looked like the easiest way for me. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 1):

use bootstrap ,its good way

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    
    <!-- Optional theme -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
    
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    
    
    
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12">content here</div>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12">content here</div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

update css and add this `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">` on head tag on html

```css
#container {
   width:100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#one {
   width:50%;
   float:left;
}
#two {
   width:50%;
   float:right;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px)
{
    #one, #two
    {
        display: block; 
        float: none; 
        width: 100%;
        padding: 20px 0;
    }
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
<div id="one">content here</div>
<div id="two">content here</div>
</div>
```